# Warmup setting for addins in Office 2013

Tags: .net, vsto, office-addins

I've noticed that the **Warmup** entry is removed in the Office 2013 version of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx). Does that mean that Office 2013 no longer supports it? 
If so, how one can keep .Net add-ins from being disabled because of long loading times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Resiliency\AddinList hive allows to specify which add-ins are always enabled, always disabled (blocked), or configurable by the user.

Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.
For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold.

You can read more about that in the [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling) section in MSDN.

Comment: So, essentially there's no way to exclude CLR loading time from the startup performance measurement? (Resiliency hive is only available for administrators, not a good option) 
The article directly states that we should "Prefer native COM add-ins over managed add-ins". So much for VSTO support.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Does that mean that Office 2013 no longer supports it?", the **Warmup** registry entry was part of an initial design but was never implemented. This information should not have made it into the documentation. The VSTO 2010 and 2012 versions of the add-in documentation are incorrect -- the 2013 documentation is correct with regards to the **Warmup** entry.